# Assign an attribute to android.TextStyle

Tags: java, android, textview, attributes, textstyle

I have an attribute to define font weight of TextView in android like this (in attr.xml):

```
<attr name="textViewWeight">
```

And in the styles.xml I assign this attribute with value:

```
<item name=textViewWeight>bold</item>
```

In the style that is applied for TextView:

```
<style name="TextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textStyle">?attr/textViewWeight</item>
</style>
```

But the attribute was not resolved. I need to use values like bold instead

```
<style name="TextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Can I somehow achieve to assign an attribute to textStyle like above?

Answer (score 0):

? is the following what you are also missing for example terminate your markup tag.

```
</item>
```

Comment: yea quickly posted, my mistake. But its not the point

Comment: I never got around to Android but this may be what you mean or some help https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1390174&seqNum=2 Guessed that was unlikely about the element termination but thought i'd say.